# ConcurrentModificationException in java ArrayList

Tags: java, exception, arraylist

I have the following code running on the only thread:

```
ArrayList<Ball> allBalls; 
ArrayList<Ball> toRemove = new ArrayList<Ball>();

for (Ball ball:allBalls) { //Exception thrown here
    ball.move();

    if (shouldRemove(ball)) {
        toRemove.add(ball);
    }
}               
allBalls.removeAll(toRemove);       
toRemove.removeAll(toRemove);
```

Sometimes it throws

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
  at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next(ArrayList.java:576)
```

But when I replace this line

```
for (Ball ball:allBalls) {
```

by this

```
for (int i=0; i<allBalls.size();i++) {
    Ball ball = allBalls.get(i);
```

No exception is thrown.

Why?

Comment: what are the next lines of your exception stack trace?

Comment: You can use `toRemove.clear()` instead of `toRemove.removeAll(toRemove);`.

Comment: next line in exception stack trace refers to this line in the code: for (Ball ball:allBalls) {

Comment: could you post it? it would be easier to understand the problem

Comment: This exception can the thrown if you're modifying the list on another thread.

Comment: Somehow, somewhere, `allBalls` is being modified during iteration. Either one of the methods like `move` or `shouldRemove` modifies it, or perhaps you have another thread which modifies it.

Comment: @Titus but how come the second code works?

Comment: @Blip you can find that out by reading [this exception's description](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html)

Answer (score 0):

Only reason you are getting this exception is that your collection is getting modified in loop/iteration (I think move method is modifying object which will get reflected in list).

To explain why you are getting exception in foreach but not in for :

foreach loop uses iterator internally. And collections are fail fast (immediately report failure), as a result of which next() method of iterator will throw exception if you collection is getting modified in the loop. However normal for loop does not use iterator , so that is reason you are not getting exception in that loop but there be other side effects of modifying in for loop like size getting changed or iteration becoming infinite.